# How can I reach a function defined in fragment from different class in Android?

Tags: android, pdf, android-fragments, fragment

I have an app which has a fragment that aims to display pdf selected with button click. I have implemented this method but How can I call this fragments function in different class where I should call this method?

This method defined in class where I try to reach fragments function:

```
fun importPdf(fragment: Fragment, label: DocumentLabel?) {
   val pickPdfDocument =
   fragment.registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri ->
    if (uri == null) {
     KycEventBus.post(DocumentImportEvent(false))
    }
    uri?.let {
     Log.d(TAG, "ImportPdf - ActivityResultContracts.GetContent() successful.")

     PdfViewer.displayFromUri(it) // Here is where I try to reach

     val documentPdfFile = DocumentUtil.saveUriAsTemporary(
     context = fragment.requireContext(),
     uri = uri,
     subFolder = cacheFolderName + File.separator + cachePdfFolderName,
     label = label?.name,
     documentType = DocumentUtil.DocumentType.PDF
    )

    documentPhotoFilePath = documentPdfFile.path
    Log.d(TAG, "documentPhotoFile path: " + documentPdfFile.path)
    KycEventBus.post(DocumentImportEvent(true))
          }
       }
    pickPdfDocument.launch("application/pdf")
 }
```

This function is in fragment:

```
public fun displayFromUri(uri: Uri) {
        pdfFilePath = getFileName(uri)
        pdfView_fragment_pdfviewer!!.fromUri(uri)
            .defaultPage(pageNumber)
            .onPageChange(this)
            .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
            .onLoad(this)
            .scrollHandle(DefaultScrollHandle(context))
            .spacing(10) // in dp
            .onPageError(this)
            .load()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be more flexible consider using live data, rxJava, or coroutines API like here:

```
private val _importResult = MutableLiveData<Uri>()
val importResult: LiveData<Uri> = _importResult
fun importPdf(fragment: Fragment, label: DocumentLabel?): LiveData<Uri> {
  ....
  _importResult.value = uri
}
```

Then observe this live data in a fragment you want a method to be called from:

```
classToCallFragmentMethodFromInstance.importResult.observe(viewLifecycleObserver, Observer{
  // call your method here
})
```

Using this approach you can decouple your code in a class where you want to call a method from a fragment, from the actual fragment and therefore multiple fragments can use this class.

Answer (score 0):

Create instance of this class and call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Add the method of the fragment inside the **companion object**

```
companion object{

   fun displayFromUri(uri: Uri) {
        pdfFilePath = getFileName(uri)
        pdfView_fragment_pdfviewer!!.fromUri(uri)
            .defaultPage(pageNumber)
            .onPageChange(this)
            .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
            .onLoad(this)
            .scrollHandle(DefaultScrollHandle(context))
            .spacing(10) // in dp
            .onPageError(this)
            .load()
}

}
```

Then call it in the class :

```
displayFromUri(Uri.parse("url"))
```